# WinRT UWP Attach client Certificate to a Web Service request

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, client-certificates

Is it possible in WinRT to attach a client certificate to a SOAP client request?
In previous versions you would simply do:

```
MyServiceSoapClient client = new MyServiceSoapClient()
X509Certificate2 cert = CertificateHelper.GetClientCertificate();
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
```

But ClientCertificate property doesn't seem to be available anymore.
How could I achieve this in UWP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var client = new ServiceClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(url);

BasicHttpBinding binding = client.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = ...
```

You may edit the cert to fit your requirements :)

Service Client Documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/mt185502.aspx

Refer to:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f1b8ef52-8c3e-417c-94b9-ba2a545e9beb/uwp-app-making-soap-call-requiring-clientcredential?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Thanks - But that is the same thing I was trying; the problem is ClientCredentials no longer has the property ClientCertificate. After reading that thread I asume it isn't possible to make a webservice call with certificate using a ServiceClient. Does anyone know any alternative ways?

Comment: I mark this as the answer because it points to the fact that what I intend to do is not yet possible. I managed to do it by generating the soap message manually and sending it using HttpClient. I really wanted to do it through the service reference though.